# OpenDJ - what are the reasons for the "Index Valid" to be false?

Tags: indexing, opendj

I am trying to create a new index in OpenDJ. I successfully added the index to the corresponding backend. After rebuilding the index, i listed the index status (using list-index-status) for that backend. 
The "Index Valid" for the newly added index is displayed as false. I even tried the option "--clearDegradedState" along with the rebuild-index command. But still the "Index Valid" is false. This happens in both cases where the attribute that is indexed 1)is present and 2) not present in db.

As a last resort I tried restarting the OpenDJ, but no use and state remains as false.

What are the possible reasons for the index status to remain "false"?

Any help here is appreciated.

Note: OpenDJ version is 2.4.4

Comment: Actually I found out the issue, I didn't supply the proper baseDN which resulted in the index status being false. It worked after providing the correct baseDN and triggering rebuild.

Comment: The attribute that I was trying to index was under the tree ou=users,o=userdata. i.e. each user (under ou=users) has this attribute. For some reason providing the baseDN as o=userdata  while rebuilding the index is the only way to make it work. Giving the baseDN as ou=users,o=userdata is not working.

Comment: As you found out, indexing works at the database suffix level, i.e the baseDN used when configuring the backend.